# How to avoid 'Invalid Keystore Format' error when running Github Android app in emulator?

Tags: android, github, keystore

Many time I download android applications from github and get "Invalid Keystore Format error" when running them in emulator. I found no way to get rid of this error. I am obliged at each time to construct a new project and copy all files and configs to it to get it running.

Is there a way to to get the downloaded app running without having to create a new project ?

Thanks.

I tried many manips to find word "key" in the configuration but find no occurence of it.